# The execution of the C binary works only infrequently

Tags: c

I have written a simple C program in Eclipse that, when run, only executes correctly about 1 out of 10 times. The rest of the time, the program is terminated with the error value "-1.073.741.819". It does not respond to any `printf()`that precedes the location in question. If I execute my program now, commenting out the for loop and the function call with pointer, it always works.
The source code is the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int getMinPos(int *argv, int argc, int startPos);
int* swap(int *argv, int firstIndex, int secondIndex);
int* selectionSort(int *argv, int argc);

int getMinPos(int *argv, int argc, int startPos)
{
    int max = argv[startPos];
    for (int i = startPos; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (argv[i] < argv[max])
        {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int* swap(int *argv, int firstIndex, int secondIndex)
{
    int temp = argv[firstIndex];
    argv[firstIndex] = argv[secondIndex];
    argv[secondIndex] = temp;
    return argv;
}

int* selectionSort(int *argv, int argc)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        swap(argv, i, getMinPos(argv, argc, i));
    }
    return argv;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Test\n"); // no printing even before function call
    int x[] = {3,1,2,5,2,78,3421,34};
    int *p = selectionSort(x, sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]));

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]); i++)
    {
        printf("Outcome: %d\n", p[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use better identifiers (think as if `argc` and `argv` are reserved (except in `main()`)).

Comment: something smells here ... `int max = argv[startPos];` and `if (argv[i] < argv[max])` ... do you really want `argv[argv[startPos]]`?

Comment: That's right. I actually wanted the variable `max` to be the index position, but took the value here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int getMinPos(int *arrv, int arrc, int startPos);
void swap(int *arrv, int firstIndex, int secondIndex);
void selectionSort(int *arrv, int arrc);

int getMinPos(int *arrv, int arrc, int startPos)
{
    int max = startPos;
    for (int i = startPos; i < arrc; i++)
    {
        if (arrv[i] < arrv[max])
        {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

void swap(int *arrv, int firstIndex, int secondIndex)
{
    int temp = arrv[firstIndex];
    arrv[firstIndex] = arrv[secondIndex];
    arrv[secondIndex] = temp;
}

void selectionSort(int *arrv, int arrc)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrc-1; i++)
    {
        swap(arrv, i, getMinPos(arrv, arrc, i));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x[] = {3,1,2,5,2,78,3421,34};
    int size =  sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);

    selectionSort(x, size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Outcome: %d\n", x[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have made some other improvements to the source code as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).